# Perl style regex - conditional output

Tags: regex

Scenario: i need to check if a filepath contains a specific folder. If so, output nothing, otherwise show an error message.
How do I do this conditional output with a perl regex (`input/regex/merge/flags`)?
What I got so far:

example-path: `bin/user/projects/prjx/src/lib/detail/file.txt`
`TM_FILEPATH/(src)?(?(1)true|false)/$1/g` however, this is a conditional match, not a conditional output

EDIT #1: I need to do this in perl-styled regex, not in perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [Conditional insertions](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions#conditional_insertions.html)

```
${TM_FILEPATH/(.*\/(src)?\/.*)+|(.+)/?1:#true:#false/i}

${                          
    TM_FILEPATH             // variable input
    /                       // delimiter
    (.*\/(src)\/.*)         // find either a folder /src/
    +                       // at least once
    |                       // or
    (.+)                    // consume the whole input
    /                       // delimiter
    ?1:                     // when match 1 is set
    #true                   // print this
    :#false                 // (optional) else print this
    /                       // delimiter
    i                       // flags
}
```

So the structure would basically look like this:

```
${variable/(regex-pattern)+|(.+)/?1:yes-output:no-output/flags}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the folder you want to check for is `src`:

```
if ($filepath !~ m:(^|/)src(/|$):) {
    print STDERR "Error message\n";
}
```

Comment: I need to do this with perl styled regex, not in perl. Its my bad, should have make it more clear.

Comment: @Serthy: So just use the regex `(^|/)src(/|$)` to test whether the filepath contains the directory.  Or does the regex have to somehow generate the error message as well?

Comment: Yes, the regex itself should do a conditional output

Comment: If this is even possible, I only found examples of conditional matching, not merging